# How to make User:User combo using Regular Expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello I have the txt file list:

```
asjd
gsgs
asda
```

I want to change the list so it is formatted as such:

```
asjd:asjd
gsgs:gsgs
asda:asda
```

So it outputs it into instead of a User:Password combo the password is just the User.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^.*$
Replace: $0:$0
```

### Demo

Comment: you are a god sir. Is there an expression to edit the second letter on the line i tried \s

Comment: Please describe in more detail this edit you want?

Comment: I have ```asjd
gsgs
``` I want to edit the 2nd spot on every line so its : ```aXjd gXgs``` is that even possible to edit the 2nd space on every line simultaniously

Comment: Not sure what else you want here.  Maybe open a new question.